# how to paginate the retrieved data from mysql database by using php?

Tags: javascript, php

Here i am collecting the category and area value from the search-form using `get` method. So as i m having 7 records into the database and i want to display only 4 records per page and when user clicks on Next button then the remaining records need to get displayed but here my code is displaying only first four records from the database but when i click on next button then the remaining 3 records are not getting displayed.

Consider `area=Mumbai` and `category=lawn`. and if there is only 7 records into the database then i want first four to get display in first page and remaining 3 into the same page on clicking the next button..

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("celebration_db",$link);
    $q="select count(*) \"total\"  from hallinfo";
    $ros=mysql_query($q,$link);
    $row=(mysql_fetch_array($ros));
    $total=$row['total'];
    $dis=4;
    $total_page=ceil($total/$dis);
    $page_cur=(isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:1;
    $k=($page_cur-1)*$dis;

    $category = $_GET['category'];
    $area = $_GET['area'];
    //$category = 'hall';
    //$area = 'nagpur';

    echo $category;
    echo $area;

    $q="select * from hallinfo where category = '$category' AND area = '$area' limit $k,$dis";
    //$q="select * from hallinfo limit $k,$dis";

    $ros=mysql_query($q,$link);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros))
    {
        $imageId = $row['id'];
echo '<div id="pattern">';    
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td colspan="2" width="300px" height="200px">
        <img src="image-show.php?id='.$imageId.'">';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td width="150px" height="200px">'.$row['description'];
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['rent'];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['capacity'];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['area'];
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
    }
    //echo '</table>';
    //echo '<br/>';
    if($page_cur>1)
    {
        echo '<a href="pagination.php?page='.($page_cur-1).'" style="cursor:pointer;color:green;" ><input style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:120px;height:30px;color:white;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value=" Previous "></a>';
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<input style="background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:120px;height:30px;color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value=" Previous ">';
    }
    for($i=1;$i<$total_page;$i++)
    {
        if($page_cur==$i)
        {
            echo ' <input style="background-color:green;border:2px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:30px;height:30px;color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value="'.$i.'"> ';
        }
        else
        {
        echo '<a href="pagination.php?page='.$i.'"> <input style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:30px;height:30px;color:white;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value="'.$i.'"> </a>';
        }
    }
    if($page_cur<$total_page)
    {
        echo '<a href="pagination.php?page='.($page_cur+1).'"><input style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:90px;height:30px;color:white;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value=" Next "></a>';
    }
    else
    {
     echo '<input style="background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:90px;height:30px;color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value="   Next ">';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem your primary issue is in your count. While you are selecting only specific rows (in the above example rows with `category = ..` and `area=..`, you're initial count of the rows is returning the count of ALL rows in the database. So while there may be 7 rows in total, perhaps there are only 4 rows with the given filter.

As an aside, you should really be using mysqli: http://www.php.net/mysqli